# What is the relation between order in a number field and order in a quaternion algebra?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, quaternions

The study of *number field theory* and *quaternion algebra theory* confuses me a lot:
there are always defined symmetrical quantities (for example the *trace*, the *norm*, the *orders*).
But I can't understand the underlying link.

- Is there a correspondence of some kind between the norm of an element
  in a number field and the norm in a quaternion algebra?
- Is there a correspondence of some kind between the trace of an
  element in a number field and the trace in a quaternion algebra?
- Is there a correspondence of some kind between an order in a number
  field and an order in a quaternion algebra?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The (reduced) norm, (reduced) trace, (reduced) characteristic polynomial and orders have generalizations to general finite-dimensional (unitary, associative) algebras over a field.

**The principal invariants.** Take a finite-dimensional algebra $A$ over a field $K$, and choose a basis $(e_i)$.
The principal polynomial of $A$ (w.r.t. the basis) is the minimal polynomial of the "generic" element $\sum x_i e_i \in A \otimes_K K(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$. You can specialize it by plugging in values $\lambda_i \in K$ for every $x_i$, and you then call this the principal polynomial of the element $a = \sum \lambda_i e_i$. Denote it by $P_{A, a}$. (It does not depend on the choice of basis.) When $A$ is a field extension of $K$, the principal polynomial is just the usual characteristic polynomial. When $A$ is a quaternion algebra (or more generally, a central simple algebra) the principal polynomial is the reduced characteristic polynomial. One can show that
$$P_{A, a}(T) = \prod_{ (\rho, V) \in \operatorname{Irr}(A \otimes_K \overline K)} \chi_{\rho(a)}(T) \,,$$
where the product runs over the isomorphism classes of simple left $A \otimes_{K} \overline K$-modules, and $\chi_b(T)$ denotes the characteristic polynomial of $b \in \operatorname{End}(V)$. (See Jacobson's The Theory of Rings, Chapter 5 §18.)

Now define the principal trace of $a \in A$ to be minus the coefficient of $T^{\deg P_A - 1}$ in $P_{A, a}$, and define the principal norm of $a \in A$ to be $(-1)^{\deg P_A}$ times the constant term of $P_{A, a}$. The above expression for $P_{A, a}$ implies that the principal trace is a linear map and that the principal norm is multiplicative. For field extensions and central simple algebras, they coincide with  the usual trace and norm resp. reduced trace and reduced norm.

**Integrality and orders.** Suppose $A$ is a finite-dimensional $K$-algebra with $K$ the field of fractions of some Noetherian and integrally closed ring $R$. You call an element $a \in A$ integral (over $R$) when the following equivalent conditions are satisfied:

- $a$ is the root of a monic polynomial in $R[X]$.
- The minimal polynomial of $a$ is in $R[X]$.
- The characteristic polynomial of $a$ is in $R[X]$.
- The principal polynomial of $a$ is in $R[X]$.
- The $R$-algebra generated by $a$ is finite (=finitely generated as an $R$-module).
- $a$ is contained in a finite $R$-algebra.

Define an order in $A$ to be a finite $R$-subalgebra that generates $A$ over $K$. When either

- $A$ is separable (think $A$ = field extension of $K$ with $\operatorname{char}(K) = 0$ or $A$ = quaternion algebra over $K$)
- $A$ is only semi-simple, but $K$ is a global field and $R$ is the localization of $\mathcal O_K$ at finitely many places (think $K = \mathbb F_q(T)$, $R = \mathcal O_K$, $A$ = field extension that can be inseparable)

one can show that an $R$-algebra $\mathcal O \subset A$ is an order iff it consists of integral elements and generates $A$ over $K$. (The implication $\implies$ is immediate, $\Longleftarrow$ is harder.)